# Scroll page when ng-show passes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here is the problem I am trying to solve: For example you have a very simple `ng-show` structure:

```
<button class="btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="volunteer=!volunteer" >Volunteer</button>

<div ng-show="volunteer">
    <p> 
        <button class="btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="">Programmmer</button> | <button class="btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="">Designer</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

BUT this div is the last on my page, so when I click the button, it opens the div but I can't see it before I scroll my page down. I know how you can, using angularJS, scroll page to the end, on click, but this is not exactly what I need. I need to do so when some `div` show-up on ng-show it automatically scroll the page so I could see whole `div` (if it fits the page).

What is the right and simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this really depends on the height of the content of the previous and the current div. I do not know what is the concern of the `$anchorScroll`, but let me try by combining `ng-show` and also `$anchorScroll`:

```
$scope.showDiv = function()
 {
   $scope.show = true;
   $location.hash('finalContent');
   $anchorScroll();
}
```

Here a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ob3TOak6wSBGTuvCWUAt?p=preview) that I have come up with, hopefully able to solve your problem